# Show template code near error in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, erb

If `ERB.new(...).result` raises an exception how do I get the code and backtrace near it?
Like rails does with it's templates.

I tried what @Nathan suggested before:

```
begin 
  ERB.new('<%= fail %>').result
rescue Exception => e
  p e
end

=> RuntimeError
```

That doesn't tell me the position of the error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
begin
  ERB.new(...).result
rescue Exception => e
  # puts e
  # or
  # binding.pry if you use the pry gem
end
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.